# Как правильно прочитать пароль для БД, из защищенного файла

Tags: php

Как правильно прочитать логин и  пароль для БД, из защищенного файла, находящегося на одном уровне с `public_html`? `include` - подойдет ли?  А можно через `include`  будет как-то узнать пароль, если скачают `index.php` Есть ли  высокозащищенный способ? Может быть как то через классы, внешние?

Сам файл защищен в `.htaccess`, и на него поставлен доступ `0755`.

Comment: А вы думаете, что если кто то сможет считать index.php как текст он при этом не сможет считать любой другой файл ?

Comment: Mike - я думаю, что в этом мире, все возможно.

Comment: Что бы php получить как текст обычно надо воспользоватся или дыркой в каком то из скриптов, позволяющей читать файлы или вообще влить свой шелл. в обоих случаях становятся доступны сразу все файлы, которые в принципе способен прочитать ваш index.php. Я бы оценил вероятность того что index.php стал доступен, а другие файлы не доступны в 1%

Comment: Человек, существуют такие бд, их называют локальными, к ним из другого источника не пролесть к вашему бд, большенство хостингов это и делают.

Comment: Mike - почему в один процент? Вы просчитали как минимум 99 вариантов методов уязвимости с чтением index.php? Откуда взялся 1%?

Comment: Человек, как это связанно с моим вопросом?

Comment: @semiromid Я вам написал оба способа чтения index.php, в 1% я оценил возможность придумать какой невероятный способ применимый конкретно к вашему софту. А Денис прав, на большинстве хостингов БД локальная и из интернета к ней нельзя получить доступ, зная логин и пароль. Надо залить к вам на хостинг свой шелл, который обратится к базе. Тут мы опять возвращаемся к тому, что сказал я. Если кто то смог залить скрипт который сможет обратится к базе то этот же скрипт сможет прочитать _любые_ файлы

Comment: Mike -  Допустим смогли считать index.php без проникновения через БД. Вопрос в том, как правильно в таком случае извлечь пароль из защищенного файла, находящегося на одном уровне с public_html? И еще, разве нельзя закрыть доступ к папке в который находится файл, полностью закрыть доступ на открытие  и на извлечение, но оставить открытым доступ на просмотр, что бы можно было получать информацию, только к определённому файлу?

Comment: Mike - можно еще закрыть папку так, что бы в неё смог войти пользователь через определенное IP. Допустим. А еще, хорошо бы на нее пароль установить.

Comment: Если вы закроете доступ на открытие, то ваш собственный index.php не сможет прочитать файл. А читать вы его можете как вам нравится, можете include, можете get_file_contents, можете более низкоуровневыми функциями чтения файлов или прикрутить какой то, совершенно не нужный в данном случае класс. И про доступ _через БД_ никто не говорил. Вы хотите спрятать пароль от БД, его есть смысл прятать, если вы боитесь что кто то этим паролем воспользуется. А воспользоватся им сможет только кто то уже получивший полный доступ к всему вашему хостингу. без вариантов.

Comment: И сам факт того, что ваш файл php уже гарантирует, что его никто не получит ни каким образом и ни откуда, кроме как двумя способами которые я описал в самом начале. И оба эти способа дают полный контроль над вашим хостингом. И все остальные ухищрения, включая нестандартные хеши бесполезны

Comment: Если использовать - get_file_contents или include, не получал ли удаленно их? Например:   include 'www.mysite.com/db_key.php';

Answer (score 4):

> include - подойдет ли?

подойдет.

> А можно через include можно будет как то узнать пароль, если скачают index.php

нет

> Есть ли высокозащищенный способ?

Есть. Но перед тем как искать что-то более высокозащищенное, надо сначала уметь объяснить, чем тебя не устраивет существующий способ.

> Может быть как то через классы, внешнии?

Никаких "внешниих классов" не бывает

> Сам файл защищен в .htaccess

Это бессмысленно.

> и на него поставлен доступ 0755.

это тоже.

Comment: А какой вы имеете в виду высокозащитный способ? Я чувствую что существующий способ  не надежен. .